Is it possible to get bytes in C++ in one line code as path.read_bytes() in Python?
In the Linux shell, I can get our soc_id by xxd /proc/device-tree/soc_id.
In Python, I can get it by pathlib.Path('/proc/device-tree/soc_id').read_bytes()
But in C++, as I searched/studied in C++17 currently, I canot find a way to read it in one line.
This is just a small 4 bytes data in runtime filesystem, and will be used among many applications in C++. So, I don't want to make it too complicated to users. One line code is the best solution.
So, is it possible to get bytes in C++ in one line code as path.read_bytes()  in Python ?
If no in C++17, and then what's about C++23/26 ?
Thanks!

Why not write a simple function for that and let your users application use it ?

In general in C++ you are not required to do any linebreaks, so you can have 1000-lines source code fit in one line if you need; Just why?

Or if you are asking "how to read 4 bytes from file in C++", there is even an example in documentation.

the standard library doesn't provide such function because it aims at making poor performance code hard to write, you need to manually allocate a buffer large enough to hold the entire file then read it, which needs a few lines, this should discourage you from doing it, reading a large file in one go just destroys the CPU cache and makes C++ work at python level of performance.

@wohlstad, Adding APIs take too much things to user(programmers): You need to tell them the header file location and function name. And, some one must be assigned to maintain the API and it's document. So, it's too complicated to just get 4 bytes from a runtime fs. If one line make sense, then no more code. Less code, Less works need to be done.

@Keelung there is no standard library function that does that. I takes a few lines of code - see my answer for more details. If you are sure the files exists, you can get rid of the lines that verify it (if (!infile.is_open()) ... ).

std::ifstream t("/proc/device-tree/soc_id"); std::stringstream buffer; buffer << t.rdbuf(); std::string s = buffer.str();

There is no standard library function that does what you need, but it is easy to write such a function.
You could implement is in several ways, one of the demonstrated below, and let all your client application use the function:
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

std::vector<char> file_get_bytes(std::string const& filename) {
    std::ifstream infile(filename, std::ios_base::binary);
    if (!infile) return {}; 
    return std::vector<char>{ std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{infile}, {} };
}

Usage example:
int main() {
    auto bytes = file_get_bytes("/proc/device-tree/soc_id");
    // use `bytes` ...
}

In this example std::ifstream is used to represent the file, and std::istreambuf_iterator to iterate over it (i.e. read it). Note that std::ios_base::binary is used in order to open the file in binary mode.
If you insist on squeezing the code into one line you could extract the lines from the function and put them as one long line directly at the client code. Something like:
std::ifstream infile("/proc/device-tree/soc_id", std::ios_base::binary); std::vector<char> bytes{ std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{infile}, {} };
// use `bytes` ...

But I really don't see the benefit in that.
